# How to grab keyboard from child controls in WPF?

Tags: wpf, xaml, keyboard, command

I have some inputbindings in a Window:

```
<Window.InputBindings>
    <KeyBinding Key="Space" Command="{Binding Path=StepNext}" />
    <KeyBinding Key="R" Command="{Binding Path=ResetSong}" />
    <KeyBinding Key="Left" Command="{Binding Path=StepPrevious}" />             
</Window.InputBindings>
```

The commands are defined in my viewmodel as RelayCommands:

```
public class RelayCommand : ICommand
{
    private Action<object> _exec;
    private Func<object, bool> _canExec;

    public RelayCommand(Action<object> exec, Func<object, bool> canExec)
    {
        _exec = exec;
        _canExec = canExec;
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        _exec(parameter);
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return _canExec(parameter);
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;
}
```

In the ViewModel's constructor:

```
StepNext = new RelayCommand(DoStepNext, CanStepNext);
```

This works fine. However, whenever I select an item in a listbox (which is a child of the Window), the KeyBindings stop working. How can I make the parent capture the keybindings regardless of which child has focus (if any).  (shouldn't the events bubble up anyway?)

I'm aware that there is a PreviewKeyDown event that does just this, but that would make my `ICommand`s useless, so I'd prefer a declarative solution if possible.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is no declarative way to make handled events continue bubbling up.

As you said, the simplest way is to handle `Preview` events.

As an alternative, you can override your `ListBox` class OnKeyDown method like this:

```
protected override void OnKeyDown(KeyEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnKeyDown(e);
    if (e.Key == Key.Space || e.Key == Key.Left)
        e.Handled = false;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I added some more details. I suspect I have some problems with my ICommand implementation, but I don't know what.

Comment: I added this event handler and whats really interesting is that it does not fire for the three binded keys (space, left and R). I'm very confused.

Comment: It worked for me in a sample project where I used a binding to the existing ApplicationCommands.open command. The three keys responded correctly. I can append my sample if you want, but there is almost nothing more in it.